# Simulating non-local (or free) variables in a locally defined struct

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures, c++14

This question probably only makes sense for people with knowledge on programming languages supporting closures. If you don't, please do not comment "why would you like to do this?": there are tons of legitimate reasons to do that.

It is common in functional languages to define local functions that capture the already defined local variables. In C++, that **would** look like (but of course is illegal):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    int f() { return x + 1; }

    cout << f() << endl; // would print 1

    x = 2;
    cout << f() << endl; // would print 3
}
```

To allow this, C++11 introduces *lambda functions*, so it is actually possible to do it in a rather nice way (though, not as nice as it generally is in functional languages ;-) ):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    auto f = [&] () { return x + 1; };

    cout << f() << endl; // actually compiles and prints 1

    x = 2;
    cout << f() << endl; // actually compiles and prints 3
}
```

My question is: now that it is possible to automatically capture free variables by reference for *functions*, wouldn't that be nice to be possible to do for locally defined *structs*? Ideally, I would love to be able to write:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    struct A 
    {
        int y;
        A(int y) : y(y) {}

        int f() { return x + y; };
    };

    A a1(1);
    A a2(2);

    cout << a1.f() << endl; // would print 1
    cout << a2.f() << endl; // would print 2

    x = 2;
    cout << a1.f() << endl; // would print 3
    cout << a2.f() << endl; // would print 4
}
```

The only workaround I've found is to manually pass as argument to the constructor all the non-local (free) variables, which is a bit of a pain when there are plenty of them:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    struct A 
    {
        // meaningful members
        int y;
        int f() { return x + y; };

        // free variables
        int & x;

        // Constructor
        A(
            // meaningful arguments
            int y,

            // capturing free variables
            int & x

        ) : y(y), x(x) {}
    };

    A a1(1, x);
    A a2(2, x);

    cout << a1.f() << endl; // prints 1
    cout << a2.f() << endl; // prints 2

    x = 2;
    cout << a1.f() << endl; // prints 3
    cout << a2.f() << endl; // prints 4
}
```

Do you know of any other workaround that would avoid manually passing as argument all free variables, or do you know if these kind of "environment-aware" locally-defined structs are considered for future extensions of C++? (i.e., C++1y?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is not available, but you can get similar results by combining functions with a combination of lambdas and binders:

```
auto lambda = [](int i) { return x+i; };
auto a1 = std::bind(lambda,1);
auto a2 = std::bind(lambda,2);
```

Depending on the amount and shape of changes, you could invert the solution and have a struct that takes the lambda with the capture and then adds it's own logic.

Comment: @Boris: For what it's worth, `std::bind` is *currying*

Answer (score 1):

I don't find this particularly beautiful, and I'm not entirely sure it's compliant, but neither g++ nor clang++ complains about this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 1;

    auto l = [&](int p){
        auto ll0 = [&, p]{ return p + x + 5; };
        auto ll1 = [&, p]{ return p + x * 2; };

        struct
        {
            decltype(ll0) l0;
            decltype(ll1) l1;
        } ret{ll0, ll1};

        return ret;
    };

    std::cout << l(42).l0() << '\n';

    auto lo = l(21);
    std::cout << lo.l1() << '\n';
}
```

I think the creation of the unnamed struct could possibly be automated by a macro.

Comment: The bad thing about it: it has to capture the parameter(s) by copy, and every "member function" has to capture it by copy, too.

Comment: This requires extended rules for return type deduction, although for strict C++11 code you can go `return std::make_pair([&, p] { return p + x + 5; }, [&, p] { return p + x * 2; });` (which does mean giving up on potentially meaningful names to an extent).

Answer (score 1):

The lambda expressions of C++ are *the* capturing mechanism and inline object literals of a sort. Depending on your exact purpose, they may be more convenient than a local struct definition.

As a motivating example, consider the following:

```
// environment
int offset = 42;

struct local_type {
    // capture environment 'by-hand'
    int offset;

    // purpose of the local type is to expose two overloads
    int operator()(int x) const
    { return x + offset; }

    double operator()(double x) const
    { return x + offset; }
} f { offset };
```

You can turn this on its head by doing:

```
int offset = 42;
auto f = make_overload([=](int x) { return offset + x; },
                       [=](double x) { return offset + x; });
```

The lambda expressions take care of capturing, the `make_overload` combinator takes care of building the desired object -- here, one that has an overloaded `operator()`. (It would be implemented best by making use of inheritance.)

This approach makes sense if you know that you'll (re)use `make_overload` from various places. For one-time, special uses there's no avoiding writing a specialty type, whether local or not.